# Confirming data in a SQL Server 2008 mirror

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-mirroring

I have a SQL Server 2008 database set up for mirroring and was wondering if there was any way to generate a report for an audit showing that the data is being mirrored correctly and failing over would not result in any data loss.  I can show using the database mirroring monitor that data is being transferred, but need a way to verify that the data matches (preferably without having to break the mirror).

Comment: I'm curious. Can a simple `count(*)` from each table not confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

Just query [`sys.database_mirroring`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178655.aspx), if the mirroring_state_desc is 'SYNCHRONIZED' then data is in the mirror. Make sure the transaction safety ('mirroring_safety_level') is FULL to guarantee no data loss on failover, see [Mirroring states](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189284.aspx):

> **If transaction safety is set to FULL automatic failover and manual failover are both supported in the SYNCHRONIZED state, there is no data loss after a failover**.
>   If transaction safety is off, some data loss is always possible, even in the SYNCHRONIZED state.

If the auditors don't trust the official product documentation, you can show the data content of a database snapshot of a mirror, since mirrors are not accessible. See [Database Snapshots](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175158.aspx). Obviously, to do a meaningful comparison with a frozen snapshot you would have to freeze the source first, take the snapshot on mirror, run the comparison, then unfreeze the source. Which implies the database is read-only for the duration, any change will cause it to diverge from the snapshot and fail the comparison. An exercise in futility, with downtime, as the documentation clearly states that a syncronized full protected mirror is guaranteed to be identical with the source.

Comment: I'd found that I could show information on the state of the mirror from sys.database_mirroring or sp_dbmmonitorresults, but for auditing purposes, they were hoping for a report of some kind indicating that the data was "production ready" or prove that they're in synch.  I'd looked at some redgate and idera tools that indicated that they could perform data comparison, but don't know if either option would require my breaking the mirror to run them.

Comment: Alternative to freezing activity at the source, you could also take a snapshot there as well. Of course, it's a timing issue for getting the respective snapshots in sync (i.e. it'll never be 100% unless the system is quiesced), but you do get a non-moving target.

Comment: @BenThul yes, that is a smart idea :)

Comment: Would this require that I break the mirror to check the data against the snapshot?

Comment: @user3457301: No. When you create a database snapshot, you're creating a "database" that is based off of the data files of the source database. You do incur some cost when updating the source (i.e. your mirroring traffic), but everything else continues working as usual.